# How to configure email settings in configuration.yml file

Tags: linux, redmine

I am new to redmine. I downloaded redmine 1.3.2.and installed.how to configure mail settings in configuration.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [example file](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/tags/1.3.2/config/configuration.yml.example) ?